# Unrecognized token in fetch function response

Tags: fetch, react-native

I created new react native app, and want to use some of my old code that fetch site status from api and I see some strange behavior.

This code works perfectly fine:

```
fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        alert(responseJson.title)
    }).catch((error) => {
        alert('error')
    })
```

and return movie name, but when I add method and headers to it, its throw error:

```
fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json',
{
    method: 'POST', 
    headers:{
     'test': '123'
    }
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    alert(responseJson.title)
}).catch((error) => {
    alert('error')
})
```

I have no idea why react behave like this, because second code example works fine on my older apps `(with react version <0.58)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your `method` only, the `API` you trying to access requires `GET` method,

```
{
    method: 'GET', 
    headers:{
     'test': '123'
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4uhxff)

**Note:** Your `headers` look weired, for available `headers` check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).